# Como cuento los registros de la siguiente consulta en SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, linq, sql-server-2008-r2

Buen día a todos

Tengo la siguiente consulta en SQL SERVER, y lo que hace es devolverme solo los últimos registros de cada embarcación, siempre y cuando su última Fecha de Entrada (EntryTime)haya sido de una sección determinada (ReportingPointID).

Mi pregunta es ¿como puedo contar cuantos registros fueron de ese total que obtengo? la consulta es la siguiente:

```
with R as (
    select ReportingID, VesselName, ReportingPointID, 
    EntryTime, ExitTime, MovementGroupID, TrackID, TrackType, 
    MMSI, AreaType, EntryLat, EntryLon, EntrySpeed, EntryAltitude, 
    EntryBearing, ExitLat, ExitLon, ExitSpeed, ExitAltitude, ExitBearing, 
    row_number() over(
        partition by VesselName 
        order by EntryTime desc, ReportingPointID desc
    ) as rn 
    from Reporting
) 
select 
TOP 200 ReportingID, VesselName, 
ReportingPointID, EntryTime, ExitTime, 
MovementGroupID, TrackID, TrackType, MMSI, AreaType, 
EntryLat, EntryLon, EntrySpeed, EntryAltitude, 
EntryBearing, ExitLat, ExitLon, ExitSpeed, 
ExitAltitude, ExitBearing 
from R 
where rn = 1 
and ReportingPointID=10 and ExitTime IS NULL 
order by EntryTime desc
```

El total lo voy a enviar a la vista por un ViewBag.

Uso ASP.NET MVC y Sql Server 2008R2

Si consideran que se puede hacer mas fácil la consulta o de otra forma agradeceré sus propuestas

saludos y muchas gracias

Comment: Estás consultando el TOP 200. Quieres contar cuántos registros traería la consulta original (la misma sin ese top)?

Comment: Así es Alfabravo, agradezco que me respondieras, el TOP 200 solo lo tengo por si  me trae mas de 200 registros no me mande tanta información, pero la mayoría de las veces son como entre 5 a 140 registros por cada sección (ReportingPointID). Alguna sugerencia de como contar los registros que me devuelva?

Answer (score 0):

Espero aún te sirva la respuesta.
Puedes usar `COUNT(*) OVER`.

A tu `SELECT` donde haces:

```
select 
TOP 200 ReportingID, ...
from R
```

Agregale esto para calcular en una columna extra la cantidad total de registros:

```
SELECT TOP 200 ReportingID, ...
    COUNT(*) OVER() [CantRegistros],
FROM R
```

¡Espero te sirva!